# getting req.getValidationResult is not a function with expess validator

Tags: validation, express, express-validator

I use the [latest](https://libraries.io/npm/express-validator) express-validator and I keep getting `req.getValidationResult is not a function` even though every example has this syntax.

In my routes I have

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const signup = require('../lib/signup.js');
const {body, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
router.post('/submit',
[
  body('username').not().isEmpty().withMessage('please enter username'),
  body('password').not().isEmpty().withMessage('please enter password')
],
(req, res)=>{
  req.getValidationResult().then( result => {
    var errors = result.array(); 
    console.log('errors', errors);
  })
}
```

I dont have anything express-validator-related in my `app.js`. In my `package.json` I have `"express-validator": "*",` in the dependencies.

If I do

```
  let errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log('errors ', errors);
  }
```

it works.

I dont know why I keep getting `req.getValidationResult is not a function` . I dont have a clue what is going on. Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

express-validator maintainer here.

Starting with express-validator v4.0.0, [all methods accessible from the `req` object are considered legacy](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/legacy-api.html) and are going to be deprecated soon.
This means any methods like `req.checkBody`, `req.validationResult`, `req.sanitize`, etc, shouldn't be used for new applications.

**Using methods from any of the other APIs of express-validator (but the legacy one) is preferred.**
[`validationResult(req)`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html#validationresultreq) is the correct way to access the validation errors, and *it returns the exact same object as [`req.getValidationResult()`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/legacy-api.html#reqgetvalidationresult)*, but in a synchronous way.

<sub>* Please note that since express-validator has changed a lot lately, I recommend *against* following tutorials published before August 2017.</sub>

Comment: Ah, thanks, it makes sense now. Hey, btw, is there an async version of `validationResult(req);` ?

Comment: @slevin no worries. No, there isn't an async version -- `req.getValidationResult()` needs to be async because it waits for all validators to complete. In the other hand, you only call `validationResult(req)` after validators ran, so there's no need for it to be async.